# Google map Polyline in React

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

- How can I draw google map `Polylines` in React Component?
- Do any available libraries to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps.) I'm currently trying to solve this with [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react) but I think it's a little trickier since polylines aren't directly supported.

If you're just trying to get the map, then google-map-react might be sufficient for your purposes, but react-google maps has a built in polyline component that looks something like this:

```
<Polyline
   onClick={_.noop}
   onRightClick={_.noop}
   onDragStart={_.noop}
/>
```

Which is pretty nice. (:

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me (taken from my real project using React and Meteor)

Libraries used in my project:

- Meteor leaflet (nearly the same as react-leaflet, I believe) https://github.com/bevanhunt/meteor-leaflet
- Leaflet awesome markers (optional) 
  https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers

*[Brief introduction about what's below here: a map will be displayed, on which there are several markers, there are polylines (red color) connecting the markers, from 1->2->3->...->end. The marker list represent for my list of restaurant, the marker will have popup containing the restaurant's title which will be opened by clicking*

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      bounds: [],
      marker_list: [],
      spots: [],
    }

    // my restaurant list contains JSON data for restaurant, containing something like ...
    // {title: 'restaurant name', location: {coordinates: ['Lng','Lat']}, /* ... */ }
    myRestaurantList.forEach(section => {
      this.state.bounds.push([section.location.coordinates[1],section.location.coordinates[0]])
      this.state.spots.push(
          {
            title: section.title,
            // ...
          }
      )
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '/packages/bevanhunt_leaflet/images';
    var map = L.map('mapID').setView(this.state.bounds[0], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
          maxZoom: 18,
          id: 'mapbox.streets',
          accessToken: 'YOUR-TOKEN-HERE'
      }).addTo(map);
    var that = this;
    this.state.bounds.map(function(coor, index) {
      var options = {
        clickable: true,
        icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: '', prefix: 'glyphicon',markerColor: 'green',html: '<span class="badge badge-notify" style="background-color: white; padding: 1px 0px 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 11px; color: black">'+(index+1)+'</span>',}),
      };
      var popup = L.popup({className: 'popupClass', autoPan: true})
        .setLatLng(coor)
        .setContent('<div style="width:250px;height:auto;">'+that.state.spots[index].title+'</div>');
      that.state.marker_list[index] = L.marker(coor,options).bindPopup(popup);
      that.state.marker_list[index].addTo(map);
    });
    var polyline = L.polyline(this.state.bounds, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(this.state.bounds);       
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div id="mapID" style={{width: '100%', height: '400px'}}></div>
    )
  }
```